# switch nested inside while loop to allow user to play again-Javascript

Tags: javascript, while-loop, switch-statement

The purpose of the code is to allow users to play the game as many times as they want. I keep on getting stuck in infinite loop and I am not sure why. P.s. I need to stick to switch statements.

```
    var color1 = prompt('Pick a color');

    while (true){

    switch (color1) {
        case (color1 = 'blue'):
            document.write("nope");
            break;
       case (color1 = 'yellow'):
            document.write("nope");
            break;
        case (color1 = 'white'):
            document.write("nope");
            break;
       case (color1 = 'gray'):
            document.write("nope");
            break;
        case (color1 = 'green'):
            document.write("yes");
            break;
        case (color1 = 'pink'):
            document.write("nope");
            break;
        case(color1 = 'purple'):
            document.write("nope");
            break;
        case (color1 = 'orange'):
            document.write("nope");
            break;
       case (color1 = 'green'):
            document.write("nope");
            break;
        case (color1 = 'magenta'):
            document.write("nope");
            break;
       case (color1 = 'red'):
            document.write("nope");
            break;
    } 

    if(color1 = false)
    alert('Thanks')

    }
```

Comment: All the logic for the game needs to be inside the loop if you intend for them to play again.  Also, giving them a way to opt out of playing again would be helpful.

Comment: Also you should use double equals `==` to test for equality instead of assignment `=`.  So `color1 =...` should be `color1 ==...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems in your code:

- The `=` operator does *assignment*, you need `===` or `==` for comparison.
- You are not using `case` correctly within your [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch): you need to just put the value you want to match against `color1`, don't try to do a comparison as if it were an `if` condition. So you need something like:

  ```
  switch (color1) {
      case 'red':
          document.write("nope");
          break;
  ```
- It doesn't make sense to list a whole bunch of different incorrect colours in different `case`s, because even aside from the fact that the user might enter values not in your list, really the logic should be "Is it green?" yes/no. An `if` statement would make much more sense than a `switch`, but since you've said you have to use `switch` then you should have one `case` for the correct answer and then use `default` to catch all other values:

  ```
  switch (color1) {
      case 'green':
          document.write("yes");
          break;
      default:
          document.write("nope");
          break;
  }
  ```

  Or in a hypothetical case where you legitimately needed to list several values but have them do the same thing you should make use of a "fall through" like this:

  ```
  switch (color1) {
      case 'blue':
      case 'yellow':
      case 'white':
          document.write("nope");
          break;
      case 'green':
          document.write("yes");
          break;
  }
  ```
- The final `if` needs to `break` out of the `while` loop when the condition is true - currently all it does is show an alert, hence the infinite loop.
- Testing `if (color1 === false)` (after fixing the operator) doesn't make sense, because `color1` won't ever be `false`: if the user clicks the Cancel button on the `prompt()` then the value will be `null`, so test for that. You could also test for an empty string. Except you can move that logic into a `case` instead of having an `if` after the `switch` statement. Instead of `while(true)`, use `while(!finished)` and add a `finished` variable that you set to `true` when the user clicks the Cancel button.
- The `prompt()` needs to be *inside* the loop, otherwise the user will only be prompted once before the loop starts and the loop will keep repeating testing the same value over and over.
- Using `document.write()` isn't a good plan, but I'm declaring that issue out of scope for this question. In the meantime, you should at least output `<p>` elements or something so that each "nope" and "yes" appears on its own line.

Putting that all together:

```js
var finished = false;

while (!finished) {
  var color1 = prompt('Pick a color');

  switch (color1) {
    case null:
    case '':
      alert('Thanks');
      finished = true;
      break;
    case 'green':
      document.write("<p>yes</p>");
      break;
    default:
      document.write("<p>nope</p>");
      break;
  }
}
```